# Switching a caption in wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, overlay, caption

I want to put a somewhat stylable (eg. two lines of different size) caption on a wordpress image. On hover, I want to add an color overlay and exchange the caption with another somewhat stylable (more lines, a fontawesome icon) text.

I have already tried quite a couple of plugins and looked for tutorials, but the ones I found so far just cover half of what I want to do. Eg: Always show a caption OR show caption and overlay on hover but never both.

The caption doesn't have to be based on any wordpress image info and can be defined in the code.

Any hints, snippets etc are greatly appreciated.

---

TLDR - Wordpress question:

normal state: Image + stylable caption

### on hover: Image + overlay + different stylable caption

Edit: 
I have not added source code for two reasons:

1) There probably several ways to solve this problem and I didn't want to narrow it down by providing one of my (not working anyway) approaches.

2) It is quite possible a "non coding" solution exists (eg by plugin), which would be somewhat preferable for maintainance. This path would probably be ignored if I posted my unsuccesful attempt.

Added images for clarity:

[normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpZ1P.jpg)

[on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by4Iz.jpg)

Last but not least, I'm not looking for a "please do my work for me" full service solution. All I'm looking for is either a tip how to initiate the switch, a link to a documentation or tutorial that actually covers both points (tutorials for either feature are plenty, but I can't get the event working for the text switch), or a recomendation on what existing plugin I could use.

Comment: Have you tried any solution using code instead of Wordpress plugins? Can you please show an image of what exactly do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry if I gave the impression of not having done research or simply asking a "please do my work for me" question. The reason for not providing a code sample, is that I didn't want to narrow things down to much. There are obviosly to approaches to the problem: Homegrown css/js and a plugin that is capaple of displaying both. I will update the question shortly with some more examples.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I found a way to abuse Visual Composers "Hoverbox" function by inserting some unsolicited html tags (br, span) in the text fields.

Not perfect and bound to produce some maintenance problems, but a self coded solution would have been even more complicated for the users.

Also the feature just isn't important enough to justify any more delays.

If anyone else wants to walk this path, be warned that the editor sometimes drops the html tags when you reopen the text for edit.